# Print use escape character, print more variables

Tags: r, printing, escaping

1) How can I print "Hello world!" in two lines? `print('\nHello\nworld!')` does not work, I get this output: `"\nHello\nworld!"`

2) How can I print `a` and `b` in one `print()`? Below code does not work...

```
a <- "Hello"
b <- "world!"
print(a, b)
```

And this code results an unwanted `NULL` at the end:

```
c <- cat(a, b)
print(c)
```

Output is:

```
Hello world!NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **cat** command:

1)

```
cat("Hello \nworld")
```

2)

```
cat(paste(a,b,sep="\n"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this I get the `NULL` after `world!`... I tried it in beaker-notebook, in Jupyter (R), in RStudio and in R Console...

Comment: OK, thank you! It works! I used `print( cat("Hello \nworld") )`, that's why I get `NULL`

Answer (score 2):

To your (1) question:

```
cat("Hello \nWorld!")
```

(2) Question:

use the `paste()` function to combine strings:

```
a <- "Hello"
b <- "world!"
print(paste(a, b))
```

Or if you want to print this also in two lines:

```
cat(paste(a, b, sep = "\n"))
```

Regards,
J_F