# Text Formatting \n included in output instead of line break

Tags: r, text, formatting

When using this code in RStudio (as an example):

```
print("Hello\n World")
```

I get Hello\n World as the output instead of a line break. Any ideas why?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807880/print-use-escape-character-print-more-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cat()`instead of `print()`.

```
> cat("Hello \n World")
Hello 
 World
```

To know more:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cat

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `writeLines`:

```r
writeLines("Hello\n World")
#> Hello
#>  World
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>